# How to change UIButton Title with setTitleForState inside a static UITableviewCell

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a `UITablview` with static cells.

Within one of the cells I have a `UIButton`. I would like to change the `title` of the button when it is pressed.  I tried to set the `UIButton` titles using the identity inspector for different states, but this did not work.

I also tried to set the `UIButton` programatically with code below.

```
@IBOutlet var calculateScoreButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func calculateScoresButton(sender: UIButton!) {

calculateScoreButton.setTitle("Cancel????", forState: .Selected)

}
```

How do you change the title for a given state on a `UIButton` within a `staticTableView` Cell?

Comment: Are the `IBOutlets` connected to the storyboard? Have you dragged to Button with a ctrl-Drag into your viewController or how is it set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by below: Actually you have set the title for pressed state and you need to make the button as selected as well.

I have taken `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` below and changing title on click:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func handleClicke(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.button.setTitle("Clicked", forState: .Selected)
        self.button.selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer makes perfect sense. I guess I didn't realize that the button had a .selected property.